# Testing a special inequality hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inequality

Suppose that we are facing a hypothesis:
$$H_0: \mu\geq 0 \quad vs \quad H_1: \mu\geq c$$
where $\mu$ is the parameter of interest and $c$ is a unknown paraneter.

Here, we only have the distribution of an estimator for $\mu$.

Is there any testing method that can be applied to this situation?

Comment: The big problem here is that if $\mu\geq c$, both these hypotheses are true. Rather than two mutually exclusive hypotheses, $H_1$ is simply nested within $H_0$. You can hardly reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$ when $H_1$ being true guarantees $H_0$ being true.

Comment: I guess you are considering the case where $c$ is positive. I made some misleading points. I am thinking about the case where $c$ is negative so that $H_0$ does not nest $H_1$. How about this case?

Comment: I was indeed assuming $c$ to be positive. But if it is negative, $H_0$ is nested within $H_1$; this is less of a problem (in that now there are at least some values of $\mu$ for which you would wish to reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$, those in the set-difference), but  there's still the basic logical/philosophical issue of what you want to have happen when both hypotheses are true. Is there a practical situation you're considering? If so there may be clues in it to a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not realize that both $H_0$ and $H_1$ could be true if $c$ is negative. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: If $c$ is $-2$, say, then $\mu\geq c$ includes all the values on the number line to the right of (i.e. greater than) $-2$ (along with $-2$ itself). Clearly that includes $0$ and all values greater than $0$. Did you intend $H_1: \mu\leq c$ for some $c<0$? If so, perhaps my original attempt at an answer might be resurrected.

Comment: Your example makes my understanding clear. Thank you.

Comment: Is $c$ a free parameter? If yes, your problem could be formulated as a model selection problem (see for instance the Bayesian Information Criterion): in this framework, $H_1$ has a higher explanatory power, but should be penalized for its higher complexity (i.e. its extra free parameter) to account for Occam’s principle.

Comment: @Gamille Gontier Could you give me a name of reference that may explain your point? I think, your idea could be very informative.

Comment: Check e.g. the Bayesian Information Criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion). Its idea is the following: if many samples from the distribution of the estimator of $\mu$ are negative, then the likelihood of $H_0$ will be low. The likelihood of $H_1$ will be higher if you can set $c$ to a negative value, but the BIC of $H_1$ will be penalized by its extra free parameter. Comparing the BIC of $H_1$ and $H_0$ will help you to conclude on which hypothesis is the most suited to fit your data.

Comment: @CamilleGontier Thank you for the detailed explanation!