# Testing a Null Hypothesis Nested by the Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nested-models, inequality

Consider a parameter of interest $\beta \in \mathcal{B}$, and two hypotheses
$$H_0:\;\beta\in\mathcal{B_0}\quad versus \quad H_1:\;\beta\in\mathcal{B}_1$$
where $\mathcal{B}_0\cup\mathcal{B_1}=\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}_0\subset\mathcal{B_1}$.

That is, the null hypothesis is a subset of the alternative hypothesis.

To be specific, I am dealing with hypotheses
$$H_0:\;\beta\geq0\quad versus \quad H_1:\;\beta\geq c$$
where $c$ is an unknown negative constant (i.e. $c<0$ and $c$ is unknown).

Is there any method or approach related to this situation?

(this post is closely related to my past posting [Testing a special inequality hypothesis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589637/testing-a-special-inequality-hypothesis?noredirect=1#comment1090772_589637))

Comment: Conventionally, the class of distributions $\mathcal P$ is classified into two mutually exclusive subclasses $\mathcal H_0\uplus \mathcal H_1= \mathcal P. $ That is the basis of hypothesis testing. The current situation is pretty unorthodox and it seems evident there would be cases where both would be true.

Comment: @User1865345 Not only mutually exclusive, but complementary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition (see e.g. Jun Shao "Mathematical Statistics", 2nd edition, chapter 6, first paragraph) of statistical hypothesis tests, the null and the alternative hypothesis must be disjoint. Moreover, both hypotheses together must contain all possibilities.

If you are interested in the probability of $H_0$ compared to the probability of $H_1$, you might want to approximate the density and then integrate it over both $H_0$ and $H_1$.

Comment: I'm not sure that the requirement to contain all possibilities is necessarily absolute. e.g. This would appear to typically preclude the testing of simple-vs-simple hypotheses as in the Neyman-Pearson lemma. (That's not to say I don't think it's generally both an important concept and a good strategy.)

Comment: @Glen_b the simple-vs-simple hypotheses consider population families with just two members, so in this sense, all "possibilities" (i.e. all populations in the considered family) are contained in either $H_0$ or $H_1$. See also the first paragraph of chapter 6 in Jun Shao's "Mathematical Statistics".

Comment: It's perfectly possible I missed something, but by recollection this is not the case in Neyman and Pearson (1933)

Comment: Also @frank, Lehmann and Romano's Testing Statistical Hypotheses in _Stating the Problem_.

Comment: @User1865345 Yes, they also agree with Shao's definition.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree that in general we only need disjointness. E.g. [Young and Smith (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511755392) write on page 65 "Throughout we have a parameter space $\Theta$, and consider hypotheses of the form $H_0:\theta \in \Theta_0$ vs. $H_1:\theta \in \Theta_1$, where $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta_1$ are two disjoint subsets of $\Theta$, possibly, but not necessarily, satisfying $\Theta_0 \cup\Theta_1=\Theta$."

Comment: @statmerkur But what is then $\Theta \setminus (\Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1)$ used for? Why not setting $\Theta = \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1$ ?

Comment: @frank Simply because $\Theta_0 \cup\Theta_1$ might not correspond to the parameter space at hand.

Comment: @statmerkur My point is that it does.

Comment: @frank We seem to disagree on the definition of a parameter space then.